# How to store results by advancing memory address in c

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

Example 1:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
void saveData(void* data) // only allow to use void* data 
{
  // ...After some calculation: 
  int inputData[5] = {1,2,3,4,5};

  memcpy((int*)data, inputData, sizeof(inputData));
}
int main()
{
  int myNum[256];

  saveData((void*)myNum);

  printf("\n%d%d%d%d%d\n",myNum[0],myNum[1],myNum[2],myNum[3],myNum[4]);

}
```

I have an int array in main, and pass the array into function saveData,

In function savaData, I save the inputData[5] into myNum[256];

**It works fine.**

Example 2:

**What if I have a struct array instead of int array:**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
struct Analysis{
      int a;
      int b[10];
  };

void saveData(void* data, size_t size)  // update here for size param
{
  struct Analysis a1;
  a1.a = 1;
  memset(a1.b, 0, 10*sizeof(int));

  for(int i=0; i<10; i++)
  {
      a1.b[i] = 1;
      printf("%d", a1.b[i]);
  }

  struct Analysis a2;
  a2.a = 2;
  memset(a2.b, 0, 10*sizeof(int));

  for(int i=0; i<10; i++)
  {
      a2.b[i] = 2;
      printf("%d", a2.b[i]);
  }

  //memcpy((int*)data, inputData, sizeof(inputData));
  //How can I copy a1 and a2 into memory space of data(ana[2]) here;
}
int main()
{
  struct Analysis ana[2];

  saveData((void*)ana, sizeof ana[0]); // update here

  for(int i=0; i<2; i++)
  {
      printf("\n%d\n", ana[i].a);
      for(int j=0; j<10; j++)
        printf("%d", ana[i].b[j]);
  }
}
```

**So, How can I copy a1 and a2 into memory of ana[2] in function saveData?**

What I think is:

I can cast data(ana) into char* to go through its address and store results;

Once I finish ana[0], I can use sizeof(ana[0]) to advance the pointer to next

one(ana[1]).

****UPDATE:--------------------------------------------------------------------

size - This is the size of the struct used to hold the results for each file. It is VITAL to pass this information. Without this size, you will not be able to correctly access the slots of the array that you have passed to map. Since results is a void pointer, in order to support multiple types of arrays, the regular pointer arithmetic will not work correctly, hence size is crucial here.

Comment: Calling data `void *` means you are deliberately crippling the compiler.  It can do the arithmetic for you if you use proper types.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So, How can I copy a1 and a2 into memory of ana[2] in function saveData?

There are many ways.  One is the exact analog of the way you demonstrate doing it with `int`s:

```
void saveData(void* data)
{
  // ...After some calculation: 
  struct Analysis aa[2] = {
    { 1, { 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1 } },
    { 2, { 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2 } }
  };

  // note: no need to cast 'data' or 'aa' as long as a prototype is visible
  memcpy(data, aa, sizeof(aa));
}
```

Of course, all this begs the question of why you are declaring `saveData()`'s parameter as type `void *` when your code makes key assumptions about the type of the its referent and the capacity (and existence) of the containing array.  It feels like you are being overly generic.

> What I think is:
>
> I can cast data(ana) into char* to go through its address and store
>   results;
>
> Once I finish ana[0], I can use sizeof(ana[0]) to advance the pointer
>   to next one(ana[1]).

Yes, you can do that, but why?  If you're going to convert the pointer's type, then convert it to the type of the data you are writing to it (e.g. `struct Analysis *`) and use it just like an array.  (And note, too, that the assignment operator works on `struct`s and `union`s.):

```
void saveData(void* data)
{
  // ...After some calculation: 
  struct Analysis aa[2] = {
    { 1, { 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1 } },
    { 2, { 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2 } }
  };

  struct Analysis *data_array = data;

  for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
      data_array[i] = aa[i];
  }    
}
```

That's pretty much equivalent to what you describe, but cleaner and clearer.

Comment: Your ways are really clear for me. However, I realize that there is one more parameter for saveData, size. And I just added the size description. In your way, it seems like size doesn't matter, got confused about the size.

Comment: @Jam, yes, in the absence of any size information coming either via a correct data type or via an explicit parameter, the method needs to make assumptions about sizes.  You will note that I already remarked on that.  Addition of a size parameter to your function makes the question very different, but some of what I said should still be helpful.  I suggest that you try to take it from here.