# Pass struct array to function

Tags: c, struct

I want to assign a1 into ana[0], ana[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TPjiH.png) only inside the storeDataHere function.

Inside saveData function, just need to pass each data_array[0] to storeDataHere function.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
struct Analysis{
    int a;
    int b[10];
};

struct Analysis ana[2];

void storeDataHere(void* res)
{
    // initialize a1;
    struct Analysis a1;
    a1.a = 1;
    memset(a1.b, 0, 10*sizeof(int));

    for(int i=0; i<10; i++)
        a1.b[i] = 1;


    // store a1 into ana[0], ana[1];
    struct Analysis temp = res;
    temp = a1;

}

void saveData(void* data, size_t size)
{

    struct Analysis *data_array = data;
    // pass two struct elements to storeDataHere;
    storeDataHere((void*)data_array[0]);
    storeDataHere((void*)data_array[1]);
}



int main()
{
    // pass struct array ana to saveData
    saveData( (void*)ana, sizeof(ana[0]));

    for(int i=0; i<2; i++)
    {
        printf("\n%d\n", ana[i].a);
        for(int j=0; j<10; j++)
            printf("%d", ana[i].b[j]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Here is the output with errors:

[image]

How to solve this if I keep this structure of function? (Not to change the function param)

Comment: you probably need to change this struct Analysis temp = res; to this struct Analysis* temp = res;

Comment: Another of your classmates has also inquired about this assignment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39419832/how-to-store-results-by-advancing-memory-address-in-c/39420073#39420073.  I suggest you read his question and its answer, as they may be helpful.

Comment: also, instead of storeDataHere((void*)data_array[1]);, try to use storeDataHere((void*)(data_array + sizeof(struct Analysis)*offset);

Comment: Also, I think that converting your `void *` to a `struct Analysis *` in function `saveData()` is likely missing the point of the exercise.  One would declare the function parameter as a `struct Analysis *` in the first place if the function was meant to be specific to that data type.

Comment: @JohnBollinger: Interesting: you've found a third person working on this exercise — there's also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39404854/c-iterating-over-an-array-of-structs-passed-through-a-void? by another user, [mdadurian](http://stackoverflow.com/users/3957782/mdadurian), with the same `struct Analysis` and passing the data around via `void *`.  I used search term '[c] struct analysis is:q' and ordered by newest.  I'd come across Patrick and mdadurian (and this homework problem) before — and not Jam.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See answer here:

https://repl.it/D2Cd

```
// use struct Analysis* instead of void*
//
void storeDataHere(struct Analysis* res)
{
    int i;
    // initialize a1;
    struct Analysis a1;

    a1.a = 1;
    // memset(a1.b, 0, 10*sizeof(int)); no need to memset cause you set later

    for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) 
    {
        a1.b[i] = 1;
    }

    // store a1 into ana[0], ana[1];
    *res = a1; // assign value of pointer res to a1 
}

// pass array struct to function
void saveData(struct Analysis data[])
{
    struct Analysis *data_array = data;
    // pass two struct elements to storeDataHere;
    storeDataHere(&data_array[0]);
    storeDataHere(&data_array[1]); // pass pointer of each element to StoreDataHere
}
```

See the link for more details. Happy coding!!

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to assign a pointer to an object, that's impossible, to have a copy you should:

```
// Copy values
struct Analysis temp = *((struct Analysis*)res);

// or
// Copy pointer
struct Analysis *temp = res;
```

Next problem is, passing elements of `data_array` such as `data_array[0]` to the function (according to your code), you must pass whole structure:

```
storeDataHere((void*)data_array);
```

Answer (score 1):

Change (you need to cast void pointer and then dereference):

```
struct Analysis temp = res;
```

to

```
struct Analysis temp = *((struct Analysis *)res);
```

Another correction (cast and pass the correct type):

```
storeDataHere((void*)data_array);
```